# Counting material objects using openCV

Tags: android, opencv

Trying to automate counting physical objects using a raspberry Pi which has openCV in it, explored template matching in openCV, but after a certain point I could realize that it wouldn't help for counting physical objects, Could anyone suggest me which concept of openCV would help me to count objects

The object's sample image is attached below
[image]

Comment: Place a ruler on the side, then try to count by ratio.

Comment: @Silencer, Do you have any samples for the same?